# Get an interval of dates from a range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, recursive-query

I have two dates 21/10/2019 and 26/6/2031, and from these two I need a list of dates with three months interval starting from the first date like this:

```
22/10/2019 | 21/01/2020
22/01/2020 | 21/04/2020
22/04/2020 | 21/07/2020
22/07/2020 | 21/10/2020 
...
22/01/2031 | 21/04/2031
22/04/2031 | 26/06/2031
```

I've tried using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()` and `LAG()` to group a complete list of dates between the two dates, but I can't seem to figure it out. I think I might need to partition this somehow, but I can't get it right.

If you don't understand, please let me know. I'm pretty new at this :)

Comment: You accepted an answer that doesn't match your posted expected output.  The accepted answer has a Start_Date that starts on the 21st of the month and ends on the 20th of the month but you very explicitly posted an expected output where Start_Dates are all on the 22nd of the month and an End_Date that ends on the 21st of each month in the return.  Which is correct?  Your expected output or the answer that you accepted?

Comment: I accepted the answer because the code was working, and I just modified it to have the dates I needed. I didn’t know about recursive queries so this really helped me :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Incremental Recursive CTEs then to be very heavy handed on the system when it comes to memory reads and CPU even for comparatively small stuff.  Are you interested in a different manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive query:

```
with cte (dt, end_dt) as (
    select @start_dt, @end_dt
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 3, dt), end_dt from cte where dt < end_dt
)
select dt, 
    case when dateadd(month, 3, dt) < end_dt 
        then dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 3, dt)) 
        else end_dt 
    end as end_dt
from cte
order by dt;
```

If you need to generate more than 100 quarters, you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=81dd1a7c9f8c29350c728c87eb353e49)**

Comment: You might want to look at the results again. You specified in your original post that the starting dates for each row should all be on the 22nd day and the ending date on the same row should be on the 21st day (except for the last day in the series) and this code doesn't do that.

Comment: I accepted the answer because the code was working, and I just modified it to have the dates I needed. I didn’t know about recursive queries so this really helped me :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Incremental Recursive CTEs then to be very heavy handed on the system when it comes to memory reads and CPU even for comparatively small stuff.  Are you interested in a different manner?

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done using a 'tally' or numbers based approach.  The upper limit of the tally_cte is 12^5=248,832 (more than recursion can produce and it could be increased as much as needed).

```
declare
  @start_dt         datetime='2019-10-21',
  @end_dt           datetime='2031-06-26'

;with
n(n) as (select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) v(n)),
tally_cte(n) as (
     select row_number() over (order by (select null)) 
     from n n1 cross join n n2 cross join n n3 cross join n n4 cross join n n5)
select t.*, cast(dt.dt as date) start_dt, cast(dateadd(MONTH, 3, dt.dt) as date) end_dt
from tally_cte t
     cross apply  (select dateadd(month, (n-1)*3, @start_dt) dt) dt 
where n<datediff(month, @start_dt, @end_dt)/3;
```

```
N   start_dt    end_dt
1   2019-10-21  2020-01-21
2   2020-01-21  2020-04-21
3   2020-04-21  2020-07-21
...
45  2030-10-21  2031-01-21
```

Comment: Right idea but you didn't make the start_dt the 22nd of each month as the OP said he wanted by virtue of his sample output nor did you produce the final date (you're missing the last two rows of the series).